# Python Proxy Requests and User Agent

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, user-agent

I was playing around with a proxy requests module that I found [here](https://github.com/rootVIII/proxy_requests)/pip install proxy-requests. I have successfully been making GET/POST requests to a temporary ptsv2.com bucket as shown in the directions and it seems to be working... My IP listed is actually a proxy server's IP. However my User Agent (in the header) still says Python Requests with a version number. Is it possible to use this module's proxy IP capabilities but also change the User Agent to something other than Python Requests? I want to hide my IP but also the user-agent as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `User-Agent` in `headers` like so:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Some custom user agent',
}

r = ProxyRequests("url here")
r.set_headers(headers)
r.post_with_headers({"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"})
```

Comment: Ah yup that worked. I wasn't sure if I should use the fake user agent module but didn't even need too. Thanks a bunch!